# Sharing remote file as a direct message in Slack

Tags: slack-api

I'm trying to share file in slack using the [files.remote.share](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.remote.share) method. It's successfully sent to a public channel but when I try to send the same file as a direct message putting slack user's id in a list of channels I receive the following error:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"channel_not_found","channel":"Uxxxxxxxx"}
```

I haven't found any limitation in the docs about sharing files as a direct message.

Request is

```
curl "https://slack.com/api/files.remote.share?channels=Uxxxxxxxx&external_id=8e1e0bd1-ad56-437d-84fe-83722789cc85" \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer xoxb-xxxxxxxx' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The userId is not same as channelId.
Required channelId can be fetched by using `conversation.open` method.

You can find the details here: https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open

sample response:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "channel": {
        "id": "D069C7QFK"
    }
}
```

You can use the `channel.id` received from `conversations.open` as parameter in  `files.remote.share` method.

Comment: Thank you! But what I can't understand is why this logic isn't the same as with `chat.postMessage` for example, where I can set user id as channel value.

Comment: In the `chat.postMessage` documentation they have mentioned that after initial message, subsequent messages will use direct message Id. https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#channels__post-to-a-direct-message-channel